# Installing latest version of npm on Ubuntu 14.04 (trusty)

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, homebrew, apt

I have

- a remote serving running Ubuntu 14.04. I used apt to install node
- a local OSx machine running El Capitan. I used hombrew to install node.

This results in the following.

**Ubuntu 14.04**

```
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install node nodejs npm

> npm --version
1.3.10

> node --version
(emtpy)

> nodejs --version
v0.10.25
```

**OSx**

```
> brew install node

> npm --version
5.6.0

> nodejs --version
-bash: nodejs: command not found

> node --version
v8.11.3
```

Why are the apt repositories so out of date? The `npm` version on the server (1.3.10) is 4 versions behind that of OSx machin (5.6.0).

This [npm issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/1960#issuecomment-395807787) even mentions that the apt repositories are quite old / not updated.

Is there a way to install a more recent version of `npm` on the Ubuntu server?

Comment: "Why are the apt repositories so out of date?" you're using a four year old operating system.  after freeze only security and bugfixes are backported.

Answer (score 1):

Download this tar file from nodejs official website

https://nodejs.org/dist/v8.11.4/node-v8.11.4.tar.gz

download, untar and install it via using the following command

```
sudo make test
sudo make install
```

It will install 8.11.4 version.

Please note that you can download any version of tar from nodejs officail page and can install it on your Ubuntu server and by using this method you don't need to update your apt packages.